# How to block direct content access by node number？

Tags: drupal, permissions

I installed the module Content Access on Drupal 7 to block anonymous user to view a content type. But I find a anonymous user can view them through URL like http...domain/?q=node/99.

How can I secure my contents?

Best regards.

Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rebuilding the permissions (in the Status Report section). If that doesn't work, [follow the issues](http://drupal.org/project/issues/content_access?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=7.x&component=All) on the Content Access module, as it is still in beta for D7.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you made the correct choice with the Content Access module. This will expose a set of access control operations under the content type configuration. (ie admin/structure/types/manage/page/access) If these flags are setup correctly anonymous users should NOT be able to enter the URL and/or access this content.

I would review all your flags, especially if you are defining 'per node' permissions. You most likely have a flag misconfigured.

Also I found the link below helpful with understanding node access control and the options we have as Drupal users:

http://www.palantir.net/blog/controlling-nodes-drupal-7

Have fun!

Nick 
www.nickgs.com